# put names in table into arraylist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have 5 names in a table and i need to put these in an arraylist....

any suggestions???

```
            int rowsinmachgrp = getnumofrows();//gets no of rows in table

            SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
            dataConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand dataCommand =
                    new SqlCommand("select MachineGroupName from MachineGroups", dataConnection);

            {ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
                dataConnection.Open();
                ArrayList names = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is yours:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
using(SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager...))
{
    db.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ....", db);

    using(SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(rd.Read())
        {
           names.Add(rd.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Not Tested!

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line where the name is being added to the list.

Comment: THX! fixed it. And I don't know what to say to get 15 characters for this comment

Comment: SQLdataread could not be found... error.. what is the usingcommand for dataread..??

Comment: The using defines the scope for the SqlDataRead, once it exits this it will be disposed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx for more details

Comment: Sorry, next Typo. I thought, I could write this blindly due to the fact that I'm writing this code snipped more than once a week.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code:

```
ArrayList names = new ArrayList();

int rowsinmachgrp = getnumofrows();//gets no of rows in table

SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
dataConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand("select MachineGroupName from MachineGroups", dataConnection);


  dataConnection.Open();
  SqlDataReader rdr = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    names.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
  }
dataCommand.Dispose();
dataConnection.Dispose();
```

Please note that while I'm solving your direct problem, you've got a lot of other issues going on, such as your `rowsinmachgrp` variable, using an `ArrayList`, and not using `using` :)